# Why do I get link errors when the symbol is clearly present in the static library I link against?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, icu

I've decided to start using ICU in my project, but sadly VS2015 is officially unsupported (i.e. the developers list the incompatibility as a [known issue](http://site.icu-project.org/download/56#TOC-Known-Issues)). Luckily someone was kind enough to fix the problems on their own and share the binaries with the world: http://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/precompiled-icu/ . I've downloaded the ICU 56 VS15 package and I'm trying to compile the following simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <unicode\unistr.h>

int main()
{
    auto myStr = icu::UnicodeString::fromUTF8(u8"кошка");
    std::cout << "length: " << myStr.length() << std::endl;

    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

When I use the compile time import `.lib` libraries, everything works fine, but of course I need the DLL libraries at runtime. When I compile against the static ones, `sicuxxx.lib`, I get link errors for some reason (there are six similar ones, omitted for brevity):

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private: int __thiscall icu_56::UnicodeString::getShortLength(void)const " (__imp_?getShortLength@UnicodeString@icu_56@@ABEHXZ)
```

I did `dumpbin /symbols sicuuc.lib`, and in the output I can see the following:

```
0E8 00000000 SECT47 notype ()    External     | ?getShortLength@UnicodeString@icu_56@@ABEHXZ (private: int __thiscall icu_56::UnicodeString::getShortLength(void)const )
```

My linker input is as follows: `kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;sicudt.lib;sicuin.lib;sicuio.lib;sicule.lib;siculx.lib;sicutest.lib;sicutu.lib;sicuuc.lib;`. All the files can clearly be opened by the linker because no "cannot open file" error appears.

**Since the symbol is clearly present in the library as shown by dumpbin, why does lib.exe have problems finding it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define `U_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION` when compiling your code so that the ICU functions are not marked as imports.

(You can see that the function it is currently trying to find is marked as `__declspec(dllimport)`, which doesn't match the one in the static library.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try to change the mode of linking of runtime in your project (either statically or dynamically). 
You will find this setting in Settings -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library (change from either /MT -> /MD or vice versa) .
Hope this helps.