# Unresolved external symbol with ICU

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, icu

We have code that uses the ICU library for working with Unicode strings.  When we try to build it, we get no compile errors, but the link fails.  I created a small test program with the following code:

```
#define U_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION
#undef INT64_C
#undef UINT64_C
#include <unicode/coll.h>

void icu_test()
{
    UErrorCode success = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    Collator* myCollator = Collator::createInstance(success);
    VERIFY(U_SUCCESS(success));
    myCollator->setStrength(Collator::QUATERNARY);
    UChar Word1[10] = _T("this");
    UChar Word2[10] = _T("that");

    // Compare two strings in the default locale
    bool result = myCollator->greater(Word1, Word2);
}
```

This program also fails to link with:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   icu_3_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(wchar_t const *)"
>   (??0UnicodeString@icu_3_2@@QAE@PB_W@Z) referenced in function "void
>   __cdecl icu_test(void)" (?icu_test@@YAXXZ)

(Is 0UnicodeString the constructor, perhaps?)  When I use dumpbin to look at the exported symbols in the ICU libraries, I see the following:

??0UnicodeString@icu_3_2@@QAE@ABV01@@Z (public: __thiscall icu_3_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(class icu_3_2::UnicodeString const &))
  ??0UnicodeString@icu_3_2@@QAE@ABV01@H@Z (public: __thiscall icu_3_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(class icu_3_2::UnicodeString const &,int))
   ??0UnicodeString@icu_3_2@@QAE@ABV01@HH@Z (public: __thiscall icu_3_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(class icu_3_2::UnicodeString const &,int,int))
  ??0UnicodeString@icu_3_2@@QAE@CPBGH@Z (public: __thiscall icu_3_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(signed char,unsigned short const *,int))
  ??0UnicodeString@icu_3_2@@QAE@G@Z (public: __thiscall icu_3_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(unsigned short))
  ??0UnicodeString@icu_3_2@@QAE@H@Z (public: __thiscall icu_3_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(int))
  ??0UnicodeString@icu_3_2@@QAE@HHH@Z (public: __thiscall icu_3_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(int,int,int))
  ??0UnicodeString@icu_3_2@@QAE@PAGHH@Z (public: __thiscall icu_3_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(unsigned short *,int,int))
  ??0UnicodeString@icu_3_2@@QAE@PBD0@Z (public: __thiscall icu_3_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(char const *,char const *))
  ??0UnicodeString@icu_3_2@@QAE@PBDH0@Z (public: __thiscall icu_3_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(char const *,int,char const *))
  ??0UnicodeString@icu_3_2@@QAE@PBDHPAUUConverter@@AAW4UErrorCode@@@Z (public: __thiscall icu_3_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(char const *,int,struct UConverter *,enum UErrorCode &))
  ??0UnicodeString@icu_3_2@@QAE@PBDHW4EInvariant@01@@Z (public: __thiscall icu_3_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(char const *,int,enum icu_3_2::UnicodeString::EInvariant))
  ??0UnicodeString@icu_3_2@@QAE@PBG@Z (public: __thiscall icu_3_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(unsigned short const *))
  ??0UnicodeString@icu_3_2@@QAE@PBGH@Z (public: __thiscall icu_3_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(unsigned short const *,int))
  ??0UnicodeString@icu_3_2@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall icu_3_2::UnicodeString::UnicodeString(void))

So none of these quite match the first unresolved external, because of the stuff at the end of the identifier (e.g. @@QAE@PB_W@Z), which does not come from our code.  Not sure how this is generated or what to do about it.

I tried downloading the latest version of ICU (60.2), but it only comes in a x64 version, while our program builds for x86.

I made sure that the ICU library folder is included in the link settings.

We also made sure to define U_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION, as described in this post:

[Why do I get link errors when the symbol is clearly present in the static library I link against?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469999/why-do-i-get-link-errors-when-the-symbol-is-clearly-present-in-the-static-librar)

In that post, they were able to locate the relevant symbol in the library, but we cannot.

**Can anyone help us understand what is causing this link error?**

Comment: How do you build your code? Can you post more details?

Comment: @pe3k, we use Visual Studio 2017.  Here are some of the build options:
Preprocessor Definitions:  WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE
Runtime Library:  Multi-threaded Debug DLL
Target Machine:  MachineX86
Additional Dependencies: icudt.lib; icuin.lib; icuio.lib; icuuc.lib; icule.lib; iculx.lib
Actuallly, I had forgotten to add the .lilb dependencies earlier, so I've added them now and find we only get 1 unresolved external, so I'm updating the original post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried building a static library of ICU 60.2 but ran into problems and I was unable to get help from ICU support to build it.

I tried downloading pre-built ICU 59.1 libraries from [this website](https://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/precompiled-icu/).  But had a different linker error and no idea what to do with that.

I saw that my code was trying to pass a wchar_t* to icu::greater(), which expects UnicodeString arguments, so I inferred that this is where type conversion causes the UnicodeString to be constructed.  I changed the code to do an explicit conversion to UnicodeString and then pass that, but I still got the same linker error.

Finally, my coworker found some information about [a potential problem with wchar_t](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-wchar-t-wchar-t-is-native-type).  So that was it - our best understanding is that since our code was originally working with MS Visual C++ 6.0, and it was able to link to ICU 3.2 in that context, it was linking with the old definition of wchar_t, but the new definition of wchar_t was changing the way the name decoration was being generated.  Adding -Zc:wchar_t- to the compile options (in VS 2017, go to Project Properties, C/C++ All Options, 'Additional Options' line), caused it to link successfully after a full recompile.

Very subtle.